# Optimal numerical method to solve BVP for optimal low thrust control

Tags: orbital-mechanics, low-earth-orbit, mathematics, low-thrust

I need to solve a [boundary value problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem) (BVP) for an optimal control in case of low thrust trajectories optimization. I want to include the J2 perturbations to the Edelbaum solution (multiple revolutions one).

In my specific case I am:

- capable to define the state equations, for semi-major-axis, inclination, raan and mass
- capable to define the Euler Lagrange equations for the adjoint parameters (lambdas entering the Hemiltonian formula)
- capable to set general boundary conditions

However, I can't understand how to integrate in time, since time is not present as a variable inside the equations and how to initialize the problem: setting values for OP and adjoint variables.

Furthermore I am looking for some tools automatically implementing and solving this problems automatically (better if written in Python), anyone know something about that?

Comment: OP = ? Please provide a link for the J2 perturbations and the Edelbaum solution.

Comment: If you mention the *optimal* numerical method, you must provide a cost function.

Comment: OP stands for Orbital Parameters

Comment: I read OP = "optimization problem".

Answer (score 1):

ESA's [PyKep](https://esa.github.io/pykep/examples/index.html) will likely work very well. It allows you to solve lots of BVP, model low thrust propulsion, load SPICE files, etc.